# Как выровнять элементы по горизонтали? Менеджеры компоновки Java

Tags: java

Нужно расположить надписи и поля вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне удалось расположить их так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В JFrame установил менеджер компоновки `BorderLayout`и расположил в окне две панели `JPenel` с менеджером `FlowLayout` Вот фрагмент кода:

```
 public class MainWindow extends JFrame {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

 MainWindow main_window = new MainWindow();
 main_window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // Панель ФИО

    JPanel full_name_panel = new JPanel();
    FlowLayout field_layout = new FlowLayout();
    field_layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    full_name_panel.setLayout(field_layout);
    // Создал поле и Label, добавил на панель, панель добавил в JFrame
    main_window.add(full_name_panel);
    // Создал вторую панель с field_layout, добавил в нее список вместо поля и добавил эту панель в main_window
```

Нужно выровнять поле и список по горизонтали и задать им одинаковую ширину. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: осталось сделать окно шире или компоненты уже, чтобы они лезли в одну строку

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Дело не в этом. Окно широкое, я скрин обрезал. Видите, на образце между надписью ФИО и полем есть промежуток, чтобы поле ФИО и список Должность были выровнены? Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: ага, я понял, задайте `setPrefferedSize` для `JLabel`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ работает, спасибо